# matplotlib horizontal bar graph color for positive and negative values all appearing the same color

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot both positive and negative values on the same bar chart in matplotlib with different colors for positive and negative.  However, it appears that if a negative values exists in the data set all the bars are colored red.  I can't figure out what I am doing incorrectly.  Here is the code.

```
df = df.groupby('price').agg(quantity=('quantity','sum'), 
                                            t_count=('price','size') 
                                            ).dropna(how='any').sort_index(ascending=True)

#example output of the groupby

        quantity  t_count bar_colors
price
9.05         -10            2        red
9.09          10            1        red
9.15       -1304            6        red
9.17         -91            2        red
9.18        -202            1        red
9.19         100            1        cyan
9.25        1596           10        cyan

plt.style.use('dark_background')
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12}) # set font size to 12
df['bar_colors'] = np.where(df['quantity'] < 0, 'red', 'cyan')
ax = df.plot.barh(color=df['bar_colors'])

# Add count as text to the end of each bar
for i, (_, row)in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    ax.text(row['quantity'] / 2, 
            i, 
            f"{row['t_count']}", 
            ha='center', 
            va='baseline', 
            color='white')

ax.set_xlabel('Quantity')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.legend(labels=[])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to use matplotlib directly, instead of plotting from pandas.

Comment: i tried fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(df.index, df['quantity'], color=df['bar_colors'])  and it plots both colors but the graph comes out all messed up.

Comment: ```df.plot.barh(color=df['bar_colors'])```: this is probably not doing what you expect. For instance, it may be different from ```df['quantity'].plot.barh(color=df['bar_colors'])```. Also, regarding your comment above, see documentation, as ax.barh and df.plot.barh take arguments differently.

Comment: Well your suggestion worked.  Have to look into why but thank you.